# Selenium python to slide a YouTube video forward by 10 seconds

Tags: python, selenium

Is there any way to slide forward exactly by given duration? 
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried till now. What is the error or issue that you are facing.Also visit [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Basically I am getting buffer health from .getText() and I want to slide the video beyond the buffered tim.... I know that Drag and drop can be used for sliding.....for that u need to find source and destination element... But the destination element is not fixed, it depends on buffered health... Is there any other method to do that or can I use drag and drop in a different way so that I can slide beyond the buffered tim? I am new to this!!!..any help will be appreciated.... Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add `&feature=youtu.be&t=<<time>>` to your video URL and replace `<<time>>` with the time you want the video to start from. However, this reloads the whole page and you have to click Play button again with your selenium script.

But if you want to forward video by 5 sec, You can just pass Right Arrow key to the element. For this, you need to import `Keys`

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

This helps in sending different keys to any WebElement such as Enter, Arrow keys, All function keys etc.

and then in your script, whenever you want to forward video, use `send_keys` method:

```
<any_web_element>.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_RIGHT)
```

This will forward your YouTube video by 5 seconds.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Basically I want to get the buffer health and slide the video beyond the buffered tim... I am able to get the buffer health..... But how to slide the video by t sec( t is the buffered health)....

Comment: @KrishnaMC How are you getting the buffer health? Are you getting it i seconds?

Comment: By right click -> go-to stats for nerds -> variable = print ( wait(driver, 10). until ( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, * the xpath. ...* ))).text.                                             I'm not getting buffer health in sec ..... min:sec format ..... I thought of converting it into seconds.......

Comment: Basically I am getting buffer health from .getText() and I want to slide the video beyond the buffered tim.... I know that Drag and drop can be used for sliding.....for that u need to find source and destination element... But the destination element is not fixed, it depends on buffered health... Is there any other method to do that or can I use drag and drop in a different way so that I can slide beyond the buffered tim? I am new to this!!!.. plz help.....any help will be appreciated.... Thanks in advance